# HTTP Communication example in native SDK for Blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am new in Blackberry 10 development and now currently working on `HTTP communication` demo.

Anyone please share with me proper example of `HTTP request and response in QML source`.

I am using Momentics IDE and QML source for Blackberry 10 applications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly would you like to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should see the [HTTP sample](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/httptest).

Answer (score 1):

If you Want it in ur Qml u will with this JavaScript Function

```
 function req() 
 {
     var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
     http.open("GET", url);//u will usse GET or POST based on the Url u request from it 
     var url = "url here";
     http.open("GET", url, true);
     http.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) 
                {
                var x = http.responseText;//load data from link in x 
                var y = JSON.parse(x)//if Data generated as JSON File u can parse it using paserer fun
                gdm.insertList(y)//insert Data in Grouped Data Model
                console.log("ok");
            } 
            else 
                {
                console.log("tring");
                }
        }
        http.send();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this syntax.. you can get full code from [sample](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/httptest)

```
RequestHeaders::RequestHeaders(QObject* parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_networkAccessManager(new QNetworkAccessManager(this))
{
}

/**
 * RequestHeaders::getRequest()
 *
 * Setup an http get request using SSL if configured
 */
//! [0]
void RequestHeaders::getRequest()
{
    const QUrl url("http://httpbin.org/get");

    QNetworkRequest request(url);

    if (AppSettings::isUsingHttps()) {
        request.setUrl(QUrl("https://httpbin.org/get"));

        QSslConfiguration config = request.sslConfiguration();
        config.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
        config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1);
        request.setSslConfiguration(config);
    }

    QNetworkReply* reply = m_networkAccessManager->get(request);
    bool ok = connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onGetReply()));
    Q_ASSERT(ok);
    Q_UNUSED(ok);
}
```